# mapkitview not showing circle object overlay in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

My objective is to show a blue or yellow colored circle of a given radius so that later on I can search for cafes and pin them within that location.

I have this code so far and I have done everything I could! There is no error and the main location gets easily pinned and the annotation shows as well but just the circle doesn't appear.

```
//  ViewController2.swift

import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate

{
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBAction func search(_ sender: Any)
    {
        //get location
        var dec = location1.text
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var location1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label11: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var baclbtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var map1: MKMapView!

    var gllat:Double=0
    var gllong:Double=0
    var loc:String=""

    override func viewDidLoad()
    { super.viewDidLoad()
       map1.delegate=self

       //pin location on required area
        let anotaion = MKPointAnnotation()
        anotaion.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(gllat, gllong)
       self.mapView.addAnnotation(anotaion)

        //zoom in to the required location
        let coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(gllat,gllong)
        let span1 = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta:0.1,longitudeDelta:0.1)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center:coordinate,span:span1)

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        //add the circle object overlay
        let _coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(gllat, gllong)
        let radius1=CLLocationDistance(bitPattern: 1000)
        let cl = MKCircle(center: _coordinate, radius: radius1)

        self.mapView.addOverlay(cl)

    }

        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer
    {
            guard let circelOverLay = overlay as? MKCircle else {return MKOverlayRenderer()}

            let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(circle: circelOverLay)
            circleRenderer.fillColor = .blue
            //circleRenderer.alpha = 0.2
            return circleRenderer
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have two maps or just one map?  Do you have the delegates setup for the `mapView` in storyboard? Don't see them in your code.

Comment: i had one map but in 2ndviewcontroller.swift file but then i checked that it was mentioned everywhere to add the mapview as a delegate to the viewcontroller so i made a new map ie mapview and added the delegate etc but still nothing

Comment: what is the delegate setup ? dont we just add mkmapviewdelegate in the class header line ?

Comment: i solved this ! i just removed the line self.mapview.delegate=self as i had already dragged and made the mapview a delegate and also removed bitpattern for radius to exactly double ! it did the trick thanks

Comment: @KhattakMahruna if you solved this then you should put your solution as an answer and approve it so that others who are also stuck on this can benefit from it, too. Also, consider fixing the typo in your title ("overly" -> "overlay").